# Wierd screen colors when waking mac from sleep

Tags: macos, mac, sleep

I have mac mini with two monitors and sometimes when I wake it from sleep I get this weird screen:

[image]

This is a normal screen:

[image]

This isn't a big issue (at least I hope so) as it goes back to normal after clicking cancel and waking up again but still wonder why this happens.

Comment: This might be better asked on Ask Different.

Comment: I think it's just a hardware bug with Macs. Someone had the same problem on a Mac, but with Ubuntu, pointing to it being hardware.

Comment: I have the same problem with a recently MBP retina bought on september 16. Any solution?

Comment: I have a 13" Retina MBP bought 2016. But this problem has only started happening occaisionally in the couple of months - since Xmas 2016.   I was wondering if it had anything to do with updating to Sierra.